# AspxSplitter set contenturl in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, c#-4.0

im going to use a AspxSplitter to set the content url in javascript and when i press a button then it will automatically change the content in splitter. but the problem that i had facing is that after i set the contentUrl in javascript but it will not refresh the content in splitter. thanks

```
 function ActiveTabChanged(e) {
                var index = e.item.name;

                if (index == "menu2") {
                    var pane = ContactTab.GetPaneByName('pane1')
                    // ContactTab.GetPaneByName('pane1').SetContentUrl("Default.aspx");
                    pane.SetContentUrl("Default.aspx");
                    pane.RefreshContentUrl();
                }
            }
```

here is my splitter setting

```
        <dx:SplitterPane Name="pane1">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dx:SplitterContentControl>

                </dx:SplitterContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dx:SplitterPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by setting the contentUrl in the splitter. thanks

```
<XF:XFSplitter ID="XFSplitter1" runat="server" Width="100%" FullscreenMode="true" ClientInstanceName="XFSplitter1">
                <Panes>
                        <dx:SplitterPane ShowCollapseBackwardButton="True" name="pane1"            ContentUrl="frmMasterEntry.aspx">
                        <ContentCollection>
                            <dx:SplitterContentControl ID="SplitterContentControl3" runat="server">

                            </dx:SplitterContentControl>
                        </ContentCollection>
                    </dx:SplitterPane>
                </Panes>
            </XF:XFSplitter>
```